# What is the difference between two greetings

Tags: difference, infinitive-vs-gerund

> 1. It was nice to meet you.
> 2. It was nice meeting you.

What is the difference between the two expression in meaning?

Comment: There is no practical/sociolinguistic difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As a native, English-speaking American, those expressions sound virtually the same.

Whether I'm introduced to someone at a party and intend on seeing them again, or if I meet someone through happenstance and don't ever plan on running into them again (sitting next to one another on a bus or airplane and starting a casual conversation), either of these expressions would fit perfectly.

Comment: +1 In general I agree completely with this.  Odd aside: I lived in Rhode Island for a little while, and met a few people who used "nice to meet you" and "nice to see" you exactly the opposite of how I use them.  They said _see_ for the first meeting (leaving me feeling like I should remember them from a previous encounter) and _meet_ for a repeat encounter (leaving me feeling like they had forgotten our previous meetings.)

Comment: @Adam That is very strange to me - I, like you, would use those in the exact opposite manner. I've lived in Chicago, Seattle, and Salt Lake City, and everyone else I've traveled within the States I've only ever heard it that way. Rhode Island must be a awfully difficult place for English learners, haha.